# Reference request: classification of principal bundles

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

I found this theorem in the appendix of Friedrich's "Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry"

> (Second homotopy classification theorem)
>    1. For every topological group $G$ there exists  a universal $G$-principal bundle  $\xi_G = (E_G, \pi, B_G, G)$. This bundle, moreover, has the property that for every paracompact space $X$ the assignment 
>   $$[X,B_G] \ni [f] \mapsto f^*\xi_G \in HFB_G(X)$$
>   is bijective.
>    2. For every topological group $G$, there exists a universal $G$-principal bundle $\xi^*_G = (E^*_G, \pi, B_G^*, G)$ such that $B_G^*$ is a CW-complex.

The author reports also two examples

E1. $G= \mathbb{Z}_2$, then we can consider $B_G = \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$  and the equivalence classes $[X,B_G]$ are in bijective correspondence with the elements of $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. The element of $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ corresponding to the principal bundle is called first Stiefel-Whitney class.

E2. $G = \mathbb{S}^1$ then $B_G = \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ and $[X,B_G]$ is in bijective correspondence with the elements of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.
The element of $H^2(X,\mathbb{S})$ corresponding to the principal bundle is called the first Chern class.

Where can I find a proof of the theorem above and of the two examples? Also I would like to find a definition of Chern classes and Stiefel-Whitney classes suitable with the above examples.

Comment: Various books come to mind: Husemoeller's "Fiber bundles" (in particular Chapter 4), Steenrod's "Topology of fibre bundles". For the question on characteristic classes Milnor-Stasheff's "Characteristic classes".

Comment: Husemöller is actually cited as a source at the end of Appendix B where this theorem is stated (not in Chapter 4).

Comment: @MatthiasWendt Actually Steenrod was my first idea but he proves the theorem only for when the base space is a CW complex. It is surprisingly hard to find a book doing the case of a paracompact base. Husemöller does the trick though.

Comment: You can check section 1.2 for classification of vector bundles and section 3.1 for Stiefel-Whitney classes and chern classes from Allen Hatcher’s Vectorbundles and K-theory notes.. you can find it here http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf you can try doing similar thing with principal bundles

Comment: You might find https://www3.nd.edu/~mbehren1/18.906/prin.pdf helpful

Comment: Graham Segal's paper http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1968__34__105_0 is relevant.